# May I know why this exception occuring while developing first spring program

Tags: spring

```
Apr 03, 2017 3:53:58 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spconfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spconfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spconfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
at springcoreproject.Client.main(Client.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spconfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:142)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
... 4 more
```

Comment: It can't find your config file in the classpath. So put it in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add the spring core jar files to the classpath.

You can download the files at http://javatpoint.com/src/sp/spcorejars.zip

For more information on setting up first spring application see http://javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-spring-application